# Merging nearly identical lines in Excel

Tags: excel, merge, lines

I'm looking for someone that could help me with this Excel issue I'm having.

I've got this giant table (like 370 line x 7 columns).

This table has a particularity, it's like this :

```
ItemA - Property1(A) - Property2(A) - ...
ItemA - Property1(A) - Property2BIS(A) - ...
ItemB - Property1(B) - Property2(B) - ...
ItemB - Property1(B) - Property2BIS(B) - ...
ItemC - Property1(C) - Property2(C) - ...
ItemC - Property1(C) - Property2BIS(C) - ...
```

So every item has two lines and they are practically identical.

I'd like to have less lines, so something like :

```
ItemA - Property1(A) - Proterty2(A) - Property2BIS(A) - ...
ItemB - Property1(B) - Proterty2(B) - Property2BIS(B) - ...
ItemC - Property1(C) - Proterty2(C) - Property2BIS(C) - ...
```

So basically merging every two lines together.

Is it possible to do? Does anyone has already done this and could help me a little bit?

Thanks !

Comment: You can do this quite easily with VBA. You can start by recording a macro and adapt the code. Feel free to edit your question (or ask another) with your code if you encounter any issue.

Answer (score 0):

No need for VBA - if you don't mind a bit of tedium! Assuming: your table starts at A1, does not contain a formula, and has a header row. Insert a column on the left of the table and populate its first data row '1' second row '2' then select `A2:A3`. Left click on bottom RH corner of the pair, drag to bottom of table and press Ctrl before releasing mouse button (ie alternate rows "1" and "2"). Insert a column immediately to the right of the two Property columns and fill E2 with `=D3`. (Being a table this will be copied down automatically, otherwise copy down to end of array). Copy entire table, select A1, Paste Special, Values. Filter on "2" from ColumnA. Delete visible rows other than Row1. Delete ColumnA. Adjust column headings as appropriate.